# How do I use a custom hook inside of useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, aws-chime-sdk, amazon-chime

I'm working with [Amazon's Chime SDK Component Library for React](https://github.com/aws/amazon-chime-sdk-component-library-react). The component library has a number of components and hooks available for use.

One of the component is `<LocalVideo />`. The problem is that it starts with the video disabled. In order to turn it on you use the hook `useLocalVideo()`.

In the examples I've seen they use a button to execute the hook:

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  const togglevideo = { useLocalVideo };

  return(
    <>
      <LocalVideo />
      <button onClick={toggleVideo}>Toggle</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

This works fine. But what if I want the LocalVideo component to load enabled? e.g., if I don't want someone to have to click a button?

I've tried several different approaches including:

1. Add the code directly to the component (this doesn't work, I assume because the hook is called before the render with the LocalVideo component completes).
2. Adding the code inside `useEffect` (invalid Hook call errors).

For example:

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  useEffect( () => {
    useLocalVideo();
   },
  );
```

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  const { tileId, isVideoEnabled, setIsVideoEnabled, toggleVideo } = useLocalVideo();

  useEffect( () => {
    setIsVideoEnabled(true);
  }, []
 );
```

How can I make this hook run after the component renders?

Comment: Call the `toggleVideo` function inside of `useEffect` to invoke the call after the component renders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should call the function `toggleVideo` inside the `useEffect`, not the hook `useLocalVideo` itself:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const { togglevideo } = useLocalVideo();

  useEffect(() => {
    togglevideo();
  }, []);

  return (
    <LocalVideo />
  );
};
```

Comment: I could swear I tried that! But, hey, it works - thanks so much!